# How do I get Myriad Pro working?

Tags: fonts

I'm not very good with computers. I'm trying to get the font Myriad Pro working in LaTeX. I am following this installation guide: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8415

I am currently stuck on Step 6 (conversion of otf files). When I click convert.bat, it creates the pfb folder as it's supposed to, but it is empty!

On the questions & discussion thread for the guide, it seems that a lot of people are having this problem.

I tried using an online otf-to-pfb converter but I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try following the updated guide for FontPro at https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro

Comment: can you not use luatex or xetex? it's so much simpler to use OTF fonts with those variants than with pdftex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks!!! It worked!! I just popped the otf files into my Windows fonts and switched the compiler in TeXStudio to LualaTeX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much easier to use OTF fonts with lualatex or xelatex as they are designed to use fonts installed in your operating system, so if switching to either of those systems from pdftex is an option, I would consider that rather than converting the OTF fonts to 256-character fonts compatible with pdftex.

Comment: here are the details: ok, so it took some messing around but this is what I ~think~ I did to solve the problem...

    copy the otf files into C:\Windows\Fonts (the files are from C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Resource\Font ).

    I'm using TeXstudio. I went to Options then Configure TeXstudio... then Build and set the default compiler to LuaLaTex. Press ok.

    Put \usepackage{fontspec} and \setmainfont{MyriadPro} in the code.